# Facebook api('/me') not returning username

Tags: facebook, api

I am trying to implement a login with Facebook - thus far all is working, apart from the $user data I am being returned does not include the username (which I know does exist).

The array I am being returned is the following (with details purged):

```
Array ( [id] => ################ [email] => #.########@#####.co.uk [first_name] => ######## [gender] => male [last_name] => ######## [link] => https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/################/ [locale] => en_GB [name] => ######## ######## [timezone] => 1 [updated_time] => 2014-05-06T21:23:33+0000 [verified] => 1 )
```

Has anyone had experience of this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `username` field was removed in version 2.0 of the graph API. I'm not aware of any workaround (short of using version 1.0).

This change is listed in the "Removed Endpoints" section of the [upgrade guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading). You can also see that the "User" reference [contains no mention of a `username` field](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user) for version 2.0, but [does for version 1.0](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user).

Not all fields are available through the API. You can see exactly what fields *are* available using the references I've provided above.

Comment: Username was removed on purpose. If you manage to find username somewhere that is a bug so please report it so we can fix it.

Answer (score -3):

Looks like a Facebook Graph API bug.

Comment: That not a bug, that's v2.0 behaviour!