# How can I get facebook username via jssdk?

Tags: javascript, facebook

How can I get facebook username via jssdk?

```
FB.api('/me',function(response){

});
```

I tried to use /me function ,but the response did not have username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Graph API v2.0, you're no longer able to get the `username` field via the Graph API:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_graph_api

> `/me/username` is no longer available.

Answer (score 0):

You can send fields request parameter to `me` call. It will return the username in the response as needed.

```
FB.api('/me?fields=email,username,first_name,last_name', function(response) {
   console.log(response.username);
})
```

Comment: Btw Facebook intends to and have removed username from the response as said by Tobi. Related comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23663126/facebook-api-me-not-returning-username#comment-36355537  but I am still getting it in my application probably using old API.